# Stationary charges and reference frame

Tags: electrostatics

I've read that stationary charges mean "charges that aren't moving". To me however this definition seems too simplistic.

If the reference frame moves with the same velocity vector of some moving charges, then the charges are considered stationary in respect of the moving reference frame? Why ?

Where i can find a more precise and complete definition of stationary in this case ?
Or, put it in another way, how would a physicist (more experienced than me) deduce the exact meaning of stationary, in a case like this? (because I can't always ask for everything on physics.stack ...)

Comment: Defining stationary is based on your reference frame. And you know about that. Surely you must be knowing what that means right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Stationary in the given reference frame" means exactly that. The charge is stationary in this exact reference frame. Let's consider this example: In our current reference frame $S$ we assume that a stationary rod lies in the $z$ axis and carries an electric current $I$. In another system $S'$ (the $z'$ axis of this system shall overlap with the $z$ axis of the original system) which moves, relative to the system $S$, with velocity $V$ in the $z'$ direction. In $S'$ another rod with constant charge density $\lambda$ lies still in the $z'$ axis. The electromagnetic fields of both rods will be the same in our reference frame, even though the rod in reference frame $S'$ is not moving at all.

It all depends on the frame of reference you are in. Nature doesn't differentiate between frames of references. If a charge is stationary and you are moving with respect to its reference frame, then it will still produce a magnetic field!